# overload greater than operator with or without friend

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Point{
private:
int x,y;

public:
int get_x() const {return x;}
int get_y() const {return y;}

Point() :x(0),y(0){}
Point(int x,int y):x(x),y(y){}
Point(const Point& P){
    x = P.get_x();
    y = P.get_y();
}
Point& operator=   (const Point& P) {
            x = P.get_x();
            y = P.get_y();

    return *this;
}
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const Point& P) {

    os<<"["<<P.get_x()<<", "<<P.get_y()<<"]";
    return os;
}


Point operator - (const Point &P){
    return Point(x-P.get_x(),y-P.get_y());
}

friend bool operator > (const Point &A, const Point &B) {
    return A.get_y()>B.get_y();
}


};
```

Here I used friend function. I can also use function without friend:

```
class Point{
...
bool operator > (const Point &B) const {
    return y>B.get_y();
}
 ...

};
```

What are the differences between them in actual implementations? Also in the second method, the code won't compile without 'cont', why is that? Even after I changed the getter function into non-const function, it still won't compile without the 'const'.

Comment: Non-member functions are preferred for operators because they improve encapsulation and are more useful when using type conversion. If possible they should be non-`friend`. As for your second question, you'll need to show how you're invoking the operator or post the compilation error, you may be trying to compare a temporary (it should be `const` anyway, comparing something shouldn't change its value).

Comment: the error message is : 'error: passing 'const Point' as 'this' argument of 'bool Point::operator>(const Point&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       { return __x > __y; }
' I have no idea what it means...

Comment: It means you're trying to call a non-`const` function of a `const` object, why does the error surprise you?

Comment: I understand ever single word of it, I just don't know what it means in this specific context. Is there any way I can do it without the word const?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to get rid of `const` here, it's a good thing, comparison operators should never be non-`const`, it wouldn't make any sense in the real world (well...except in quantum mechanics).

Comment: it's a toy class, just for the sake of understanding the language. There has to be a reason why const is there. By the way if I change the friend function into a const function, it won't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've already noticed, comparison operator overloads can either be implemented as a member function or as a non-member function.

As a [rule of thumb](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) you should implement them as a non-member non-`friend` function where possible, as this increases encapsulation, and it allows (non-`explicit`) conversion constructors to be used on either side of the operator.

Say for instance your `Point` class for whatever reason had an `int` conversion constructor:

```
Point(int x);
```

With a non-member comparison operator you can now do the following:

```
Point p;
p < 3; // this will work with both a member and non-member comparison
3 < p; // this will **only** work if the comparison is a non-member function
```

You also seem to be confused about when to use `const`, again as a rule of thumb for comparison operators you should always use `const` wherever possible, because comparisons logically do not involve any change to the object.

As `Point` is a very small class you could also take it by value instead, so in order of most to least preferable your options are:

```
// Non-member, non-friend
bool operator>(Point const& A, Point const& B);
bool operator>(Point A, Point B);

// Non-member, friend    
friend bool operator>(Point const& A, Point const& B);
friend bool operator>(Point A, Point B);

// Member
bool Point::operator>(Point const& B) const;
bool Point::operator>(Point B) const;
```